# How to backup symbolic link paths?

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link

Is it possible to backup and restore the created symbolic link paths? Where Windows 7 stores the data for the symbolic links? I looked in the registry but i couldn't find any data there.

Comment: disk links are Filesystem level phenoma, so they will exist in the Filesystem Metadata files, not the OS. the OS barely knows that the link its traversing is a link at all.

Answer (score 2):

you can run `dir /AL /S c:\` to list all junctions and symlinks, then stash that info somewhere safe.  Filter out the junctions (they are listed as such) if you don't care about them, and change drive letters as appropriate.